# Azure Active Directory graph api - How to regenerate expired page token

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Azure AD graph REST API to get all users on the Azure Active Directory. I am also using paging while getting those user. 
At the end of each page, api returns token for the next page. Which is used to get next page of users.

It looks like this - `"odata.nextLink": "directoryObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User?$skiptoken=X'226370740200010000003E3ACDE316230633836636636373430323861666235626436306537366132306139407361696C706F69AEFDE746465762E6F4F4F4F418F736F66742E636F6D29557365725F383461663866351238412782482433372D626439312D336239633930373536383464B900CCCC00001111000000'"
}`

For some reason if there is delay in using this next page token, it expires. API throws error 'Bad Request The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request.'

So how to regenerate valid page token for next page without starting again from the beginning ? 
What is the default validity for the page token ? I guess it is 1 hour. Is it possible to increase this time ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking around on [existing graph documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options), there is no mention of any explicit manner to extend this token.

Considering there does not seem to be a way to extend it, you should make your app code **advance as much pages as it did** (caching it somewhere), to continue from there.

You should also consider restarting from the beginning, as one hour can be long enough to have your user list potentially been modified.